# SonarQube - Some configuration tabs are rendered as empty

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'v tried both 5.6.2 and 6.0 but the following configuration tabs are always rendered as empty pages:
* General -> Email
* Licenses
* Security -> Encryption

The one I actual need is the email settings, I cannot configure notifications.
I don't see any errors in the log, the only one warning is: "JNA not found. native methods will be disabled."

What are the requirements to show this configuration tab?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what's your browser ? Did you try to clean-up the browser cache ?

Comment: I suggest to try in incognito mode